# how to query a specific string from a list of string in Android RoomDB

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Is it possible to query a specific string from a list of string in an Entity in RoomDB?

here is my Entity

```
 @Entity
data class Radical(
@PrimaryKey
val pkey: Int = 0,
@ColumnInfo(name="radical_name")
val radicalName: String,
@ColumnInfo(name="radical_strokes")
val radicalStrokes:List<String>
)
```

Then my interface would be like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM RADICAL WHERE radicalStrokes == :radicalStrokes")
suspend fun fetchRadical(radicalStrokes: String): Radical
```

It returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` (same like contains() method) instead of ==

for example

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM RADICAL WHERE radicalStrokes LIKE '%' ||  :radicalStrokes || '%' ")
suspend fun fetchRadical(radicalStrokes: String): Radical
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ColumnInfo(name="radical_strokes")
val radicalStrokes:List<String>
)
```

you are using list and you're searching for string

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM RADICAL WHERE radicalStrokes == :radicalStrokes")
suspend fun fetchRadical(radicalStrokes: String): Radical
```

so try to use LIKE for that as Eslam answer